# Repository save() is not working

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am currently playing around with spring-data-neo4j and have a really weird behaviour around persisting data.

I read the [Getting Started guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/) and looked through the [Good Relationships: The Spring Data Neo4j Guide Book](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/). Loading existing nodes works, after getting rid of smaller issues and imperfections (like using spring-ogm 1.1.4 to get rid of the neo4j-server dependency).

Let's have a look on my code...

This is entity:

```
package sdn.test.model;

import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GraphId;
import org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity;

@NodeEntity
public class TestUser {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public TestUser() {
    }

    public TestUser(Long id, String username, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        TestUser testUser = (TestUser) o;

        if (getId() != null ? !getId().equals(testUser.getId()) : testUser.getId() != null) return false;
        if (getUsername() != null ? !getUsername().equals(testUser.getUsername()) : testUser.getUsername() != null)
            return false;
        return getPassword() != null ? getPassword().equals(testUser.getPassword()) : testUser.getPassword() == null;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getId() != null ? getId().hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (getUsername() != null ? getUsername().hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (getPassword() != null ? getPassword().hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TestUser{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                "}";
    }
}
```

And this is my repository:

```
package sdn.test.repository;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.GraphRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import sdn.test.model.TestUser;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<TestUser> {

    @Query("MATCH (user:TestUser{username: {username}, password: {password}}) RETURN user")
    TestUser findByUsernameAndPassword(@Param("username") String username, @Param("password") String password);

}
```

Here is the neo4j configuration:

```
package sdn.test.config;

import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.Neo4jServer;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.server.RemoteServer;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;


@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("sdn.test.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
        return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7474", "neo4j", "test");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("sdn.test.model");
    }

}
```

Everything together lives in a simple Spring Boot application and I try to do the entity creation in this test class:

```
package sdn.test;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import sdn.test.config.Neo4jConfig;
import sdn.test.model.TestUser;
import sdn.test.repository.UserRepository;

import java.util.Date;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {
        Neo4jConfig.class})
public class SimpleNeo4jTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void createNewUser() {
        long timeOffset = (new Date()).getTime();
        String username = "test" + timeOffset;
        String password = "password@" + timeOffset;

        TestUser newUser = new TestUser(timeOffset, username, password);
        userRepository.save(newUser);

        // Try to load the user
        TestUser actualUser = userRepository.findByUsernameAndPassword(username, password);

        assertThat(actualUser, equalTo(newUser));
    }
}
```

Last but not least, here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.h0lg.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-sdn4-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

There is no error thrown when I call `userRepository.save()` and checking the "remote" server confirms the red test result.

Explicitly giving the label name with `@GraphEntity(label = "TestUser")` doesn't help. Using transactions explicitly didn't help either.

Any ideas and hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: Please could you turn on debug logging and post the log trace of the save request, so we have a bit more information to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're setting the @GraphId of your `TestUser` node entity via the test:

```
TestUser newUser = new TestUser(timeOffset, username, password);

public TestUser(Long id, String username, String password) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}
```

Application code should never assign a value to the @GraphId. Could you remove that and see if it helps?

Comment: That's it. But this changed in one of the latest versions, didn't it? I know I tried this earlier and I got a NPE due to `id` being null...

Comment: Your NPE might have disappeared due to bug fixes around the OGM's dependence on the entity equals(). But the stance that the @GraphId field should never be set has been the same right from the first release

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)